# Replacement for jade mixins in angularjs

Tags: node.js, angularjs, express, pug, mixins

Related to that question: [Jade Mixins in AngularJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18507062/jade-mixins-in-angularjs/21293916#21293916)

I have the following (simplified) code:

```
tr(ng-repeat="avatar in avatars")
    +avatarRow({name: '{{avatar.name}}'})


mixin avatarRow(avatar)
    td avatar.name
```

Since it is a bit dirty to resolve the "avatar" object before it is passed to the mixin I would prefer a more angular like solution.

Still it would be cool, to keep the mixin code in the same file, but thats not a must. As far as I see, with `ngInclude` I can no pass any args. So how to handle that?

Continued with this:

```
tr(ng-repeat="avatar in avatars")
    +avatarRow({name: '{{avatar}}'})


mixin avatarRow(avatar)
    var x = JSON.parse(avatar);
    td x.name
```

I checked that typeof avatar is string, I can even print it and pass the result to JSON.parse() myself but jade throws a SyntaxError:

```
Unexpected token { 
    at Object.parse (native)
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13422966/how-to-specify-model-to-a-nginclude-directive-in-angularjs/20639139#20639139 provides a nice solution but it breaks my Jade IDE support, when i place jade code inside a script ;) But thats smething I could work arround with another mixin.

Comment: hm does not realy fork for me yet.